# Best practice for Bootstrap styling Wordpress elements in Gatsby?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, gatsby

general question here. I’m relatively new to Gatsby and headless Wordpress. I understand I can apply global styles on the Gatsby side, but I have certain elements on the Wordpress side that need specific styles. For example, I have a hero image on my home page in WP that needs an my-5 bootstrap class. Currently I’m just going into the HTML editor in Gutenberg and wrapping it in a div with class my-5. It’s rendering totally fine in Gatsby but it just feels a little messy to me. Is there a better way to do this that doesn’t involve having my Bootstrap classes living in both Gatsby and WP?

Comment: hero image set as featured image? just add styling to your gatsby template when you are displaying featured image

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it will require a bit of refactoring.

Basically, just create new fields in Wordpress for every piece of data. For example: `main-image`, `header-image`, `title`, `subtitle`, `body`, ...

Then, you will just get raw data when pulling from the Wordpress API, instead of getting HTML (unless you actually want HTML, like the `body` field maybe). You can just do all the styling / logic in Gatsby only.

Comment: Interesting, I like this idea. So using ACF or something like it?